# Jpackage MSI upgrade does not complete if application is open

Tags: javafx, jpackage

I'm working on a MSI installer for our java app using Jpackage.

**Versions:**

```
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.1+12 (build 17.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing

jpackage 17.0.1

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
OS Version:                10.0.17763 N/A Build 17763
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

**Jpackage Usage:**

```
jpackage --input ./home ^
  --name "Acme Application" ^
  --main-jar app.jar ^
  --main-class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher ^
  --java-options "-splash:$APPDIR/splash.png" ^
  --java-options -Xmx2g ^
  --icon resources/package.ico ^
  --win-shortcut ^
  --win-menu ^
  --type msi ^
  --app-version %1
```

**Upgrade Process**

The installation works fine and everything runs well. The upgrade process also works fine under normal circumstances. When the user tries to run the new MSI package while the application is still running, the MSI installer prompts the user to close the application before continuing:

[image: close application dialog]

Selecting to close the application and continue causes the application to close on the users desktop but the installer then prompts the user again with the same dialog. Selecting the same option (close and continue), allows the installer to complete but the user is then warned that they need to restart.

[image: restart dialog]

Upon restarting, it appears that application version 1.0.0 is still running. Checking the jar file signature before and after shows that installer failed to overwrite the original.

**Event Viewer**

Checking the event viewer, I'm only seeing a few things of interest:

```
Windows Installer requires a system restart. Product Name: *******. Product Version: 1.0.1. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Unknown. Type of System Restart: 1. Reason for Restart: 0.
```

and

```
The Windows Installer initiated a system restart to complete or continue the configuration of '*******'.
```

**Failing to Stop the Application**

I also noticed that the application is not ***completely*** stopping. Looking at the task manager, it shows the application running under the user and then moves to background processes. This leads me to believe that it's still locking the jar file. The application stops normally under other circumstances so I'm not sure what's different here.

I'm assuming that I need to solve this mystery but I have no idea why the application wouldn't respond to the installer's close signal while working with everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've done some digging and this is related to JavaFX's lifecycle. Simply overriding the Application.stop method is not enough to properly shutdown on these types of close requests.

Two changes to my application fixed the issue:

**Register a EventHandler on the primary stage onCloseRequest**

Here I initialize my spring application as well as register the event handler to stop the application:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    applicationContext.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(stage));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> stop());
}
```

**Ensure you have a call to System.exit in your EventHandler**

Platform.exit is not enough to close the application under these circumstances:

```
@Override
public void stop() {
    log.info("Shutting down application...");
    applicationContext.close();
    Platform.exit();
    log.info("Shutdown complete");

    // System.exit is required or the app will move to a background process on uninstall/upgrade
    // events from Windows MSI installer
    System.exit(0);
}
```